# Q&A: Is it possible to delegate another contract right to mint a token on behalf of others?

Tags: tokens, erc-721, ethereum-classic

**This part of own Q&A serial of posts which shares knowledge gained during work on one project**

My project implies another contract should transfer a token by some condition. Is it possible to delegate another contract right to mint a token on behalf of others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is necessary for the ERC721 standard as everyone can mint this token. However, it is possible to delegate another user or contract right to transfer the token.

```
contract.approve(to, tokenId)
```

ERC721 API functions:

```
Functions

    balanceOf(owner)

    ownerOf(tokenId)

    safeTransferFrom(from, to, tokenId)

    transferFrom(from, to, tokenId)

    approve(to, tokenId)

    getApproved(tokenId)

    setApprovalForAll(operator, _approved)

    isApprovedForAll(owner, operator)

    safeTransferFrom(from, to, tokenId, data)
```